# GitLab registry cleanup policy: how to keep most recent n tags, but delete others?

Tags: gitlab

I'm a bit confused about GitLab's registry cleanup policy.

I have several registries with tags for the image `foo` being pushed every few weeks or so, named `foo:v1.0.0`, `foo:v1.0.1` etc. The tag `latest` is always pushed alongside the versioned tags. However, `latest` is never used in production in order to pin the dependencies.

I would like to keep the most recent 1 tag, and clear out any tags older than, say, 30 days.

I currently have the following policy set:

[image]

I would expect only two tags to be inside my repository (`latest` and, e.g. `foo:v1.0.1`), yet, there are 15, dating back to 6 months ago and earlier.

Now, when I look at the "Keep the most recent line" — what does "1 tag per image name" mean here, exactly? Is the "image name" the name of the image, e.g. `foo`, then the policy should not leave 15 images in my repository, only 1.

If "image name" is actually the name plus the tag (e.g., `foo:v1.0.0`), what is the purpose of this setting? It means that any image will be kept!

I guess I could remove the keep rules, but I also do not want to simply delete all images except the `latest` one, since `latest` is never used in production, and in case that I don't update an image within 30 days, that will be deleted to, and I cannot deploy anymore.

Is there a good solution to this, other than writing my own cleanup script?

Comment: FWIW, I created a [script to accomplish what I need](https://gist.github.com/slhck/5d13a47154897bc408c345dd3e65a745).

Comment: My understanding is that the `.*` in the keep regex means to me you would keep every tag, nothing would be removed. The complete cleanup logic is [described here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/container_registry/reduce_container_registry_storage.html#how-the-cleanup-policy-works).

Comment: Based on a quick look at your script, I think removing the keep rule altogether should do the same thing as your script when you set "keep the most recent" to the same value as your `TAGS_TO_KEEP` variable. -- The Keep N rule will take precedence over the "remove older than" so you don't have to worry about not updating your image every 30 days.

Answer (score 1):

> what does "1 tag per image name" mean here, exactly?

"image name" really means 'repository' in the docker registry API sense of the word. I'm guessing the GitLab UI avoids this term to prevent conflation with 'repository' in the git/project sense of the word, since it would be confusing because a single GitLab project/repo can hold many separate docker images.

So, suppose you have two images `myproject/foo` and `myproject/bar`, "1 tag per image" means 1 tag for the image `myproject/foo` and 1 tag for `myproject/bar`. It does *not* mean a combination of image and tag.

Your keep rule of `.*` is preventing any tags from being cleaned up, per step 4 of [the cleanup policy](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/container_registry/reduce_container_registry_storage.html#how-the-cleanup-policy-works):

> The cleanup policy:
>
> 1. Collects all tags for a given repository in a list.
> 2. Excludes the tag named `latest` from the list.
> 3. Evaluates the `name_regex` (tags to expire), excluding non-matching names from the list.
> 4. **Excludes from the list any tags matching the `name_regex_keep` value (tags to preserve).**
> 5. Excludes any tags that do not have a manifest (not part of the options in the UI).
> 6. Orders the remaining tags by `created_date`.
> 7. Excludes from the list the N tags based on the `keep_n` value (Number of tags to retain).
> 8. Excludes from the list the tags more recent than the `older_than` value (Expiration interval).
> 9. Finally, the remaining tags in the list are deleted from the Container Registry.

So, you would probably want to change your keep regex to match only the images you would want to keep -- like the tags you use in production (e.g. `v.+` to match tags starting with `v`).

Comment: I want to keep production tags, but only the most recent N ones, not all. So if I set a regex starting with v, it'd be the same as now, essentially never deleting any production tags, right? So I guess I should remove the regex entirely?

Comment: Ah I see. I'm not sure you can get that precise behavior unless you exclusively use "production" tags on a given image -- in which case, yes, removing the regex entirely would get you that effect. But if you use other tags in addition to those, you may cause a production tag to no longer be in the N latest -- say, if you push several non-prod tags.

Comment: Yeah, I think just removing the regex will probably achieve what I need. I will try that and report back.

Answer (score 1):

I've given up trying to understand how the cleanup policies work, and instead wrote a Python script that does the entire cleanup.

The code can be found in [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/slhck/ff4c289753359f7ce211ef1c210b4b86).

The basic idea is to:

- Fetch all tags
- Exclude the ones containing "latest"
- Extract, if any, a tag prefix (e.g. `customer-v1.2.3`)
- Group by prefixes, and for each prefix group, keep at most N tags
- Delete the others